# center div by other location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a responsive menu, to my menu item with class `.current` need to been in center of screen. I tried to make a jQuery, but I dont know how to set the position to center for `.current` item.

There's my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9c7a94L4/)

And there is my jQuery, what I tried to make

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(updateBoxDimension);
    $(window).on('resize', updateBoxDimension);
});


function updateBoxDimension() {
    var current = $(".menu .item.current");
    var pozition = current.position();
    var windows = $(window).width();
}
```

Comment: You want to have focus on `.current` element?

Comment: actually yes, to its been scrolled to center

Answer (score 1):

How about using css to solve the problem?

```
.current{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: Maybe some z-index things are needed.

Comment: I've always used a negative margin to bring my element back center, but that always required knowing the width, but with your method, you don't need to have a width and it can still bring it back via `transform: translate`. I never knew about this...thanks a lot!

Comment: @Waxi If you are satisfied with my answer, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll to `.current` element no matter where it is, you'll have to do some calculation:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(updateBoxDimension);
    $(window).on('resize', updateBoxDimension);
});


function updateBoxDimension() {
    var current = $(".menu .item.current");
    var pozition = $(current).position().left;
    var currentWidth = $('.current').width();
    var menuWidth = $('.menu').width();
    var requiredLeftDistance = ((menuWidth-currentWidth)/2);
    var distanceToMove = (pozition-requiredLeftDistance);
    $('.menu').animate({
            scrollLeft: distanceToMove
        }, 200);
}
```

```css
.menu{
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.menu .items{}

.menu .items .item{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:7px 15px;
}

.menu .items .item.current{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">Menu item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Menu item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Menu item 3</div>
    <div class="item current">Menu item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Menu item 5</div>
    <div class="item" >Menu item 6</div>
    <div class="item ">Menu item 7</div>
    <div class="item">Menu item 8</div>
    <div class="item">Menu item 9</div>
    <div class="item">Menu item 10</div>
    <div class="item">Menu item 11</div>
    <div class="item">Menu item 12</div>
    <div class="item">Menu item 13</div>
    <div class="item">Menu item 14</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, you take your current element position. Then calculate where it has to be. And finally you move it for the difference. If difference is negative it won't move, because it's already visible.
https://jsfiddle.net/9c7a94L4/5/

Answer (score 0):

In css:

```
.current {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The auto margin for left and right ensures the horizontal centering.